# Webpage dimensions based on user's screen resolution

Tags: html, css

Now that I've nailed how I want my website to look, I need a way to make it look good on any screen resolution. To make my life easier, I set static dimensions while I was playing with the design. The dimensions are set at 1040x690. At home I use 1920x1080 resolution, and my boss's laptop is on 800x600. The website looks either too big or too small.

I realize I can set things by percentage in my CSS to fix this. The problem is the webpage has images of varying sizes based on the dimensions of my design. How do I make the dimensions of my website dynamic without making it look bad with the pictures being sized the way they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *responsive design* and is usually applied to re-formatting your layout for mobile devices. Formatting for different sizes is usually done using *Media Queries* which apply different stylesheets based on the user's screen size.

In general, sites don't make different versions for different resolutions of the non-mobile version and stick to common resolutions: generally 960-wide. The added complexity of supporting EVERY resolution is usually not worth it once you get into supporting different sizes of images.

In short, you CAN support various resolutions, but it's a lot more work. Consider your audience and make it work for the majority of people.

98% of people have a monitors larger than 1024-wide, so your boss is the odd one out.

See: http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-ww-monthly-201106-201206

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I ran into when trying to research this was I had no idea what to Google.

I'll just have to put up with the extra work since my boss is the one who needs to see my design the way I meant it to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with **media queries**.

for example, something like this

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
         div#container {width: 768px;}

        }
```

Try this links

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries
http://www.danstorm.com/dan-storm-article-css-15.html

Comment: Very useful link. I think you may have lead me to the answer I was looking for. I'll know once I get to play around with it a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use CSS framework and prototype design called Foundation. You are able to find it at the follwoing URL:
http://foundation.zurb.com/

It will offer flexible and easy ti use design for your web page suitable for many devices and resolutions.

Comment: I'm trying to be lazy and not re-design too much. But if I do, I might try this.

Comment: I encourage you to try it, it will helps you and it may not require to redesign all of your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by scaling your *html* division(i.e. area covered by HTML tag -whole site) by *scale* property of CSS.
 CSS Provides property named scale which can scale the size(width x height) of any element in the document.

For example,

`<div id ="t_div"></div>`

Now we can scale the size of the division as follow:

`#t_div
{
-moz-transform:scale(1.5,1.5); //for Firefox
}`

Above code will increase the size of division by x1.5 .
you can use this property of CSS to scale your website's main Tag(<html>) to adjust size according to screen size.
Link given below describe in very thorough manner about how to apply this *scale* property dynamically to your site.
Here have a look at this. http://khuntronak.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-fixsolve-screen-resolution.html

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in the head section : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">